# Push to Bitbucket repo silently fails and nothing changes

Tags: git, bitbucket

In the past I've used svn and cvs, but never BitBucket or Git. I just got a BitBucket account with an empty project associated.

I read [Getting Started with Bitbucket](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Using+your+bitbucket+Repository) and on my BitBucket page that I am supposed to do the following:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/REST_OF_URL/...
```

I use the URL provided by Git; it successfully accepts my password without any trouble. It does, however print the following:

> warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

This made sense to me, because I just signed up for BitBucket.

This makes a directory called `myproject`. I then copied a file to that directory and added it to the repository:

```
cd myproject
echo 'Hello Git!' > hello.txt
git add hello.txt
```

I checked the status:

```
git status
```

and saw that hello.txt was recognized as a new file.

I then tried to push the file to the server:

```
git push https://bitbucket.org/REST_OF_URL/...
```

again, I typed in my password and it didn't complain. 
It reads:

> Everything up-to-date

But the file has *not* shown up in my online Git project. I also noticed there is a `git commit` command. I tried this as well:

```
git commit -m "Initial project set up"
```

The output reads:

> Your name and email address were configured automatically based on
>   your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.

Since the file still hasn't shown up in my directory, I feel like I must have made a *local* commit on my own machine. Can anyone help me by telling me

- What I'm missing to set up a simple project with Git
- Where I've committed these files on my local machine (I'm hard up for disk space and don't want any clutter)

As another user experienced from [the Git BitBucket manual](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Sharing+Code+in+Bitbucket) it transfers *only* when you push with

```
git push origin master
```

but does *not* work when you push with

```
git push
```

This resolves my issue, but I still do not know why this happens.

Comment: Maybe you should read that [help page](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Getting+Started+with+Bitbucket) you linked from the beginning, because apparently you didn’t follow step 1 and 2 completely. Those are important!

Comment: I really think I did follow the instructions; the issue turned out to be something seen by other people (comments on http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Sharing+Code+in+Bitbucket). [Maybe] Please don't be snarky or condescending, because [apparently] it ruins stackoverflow! [It's important!]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simple solution is push with master branch at first time:

```
$ git push origin master
```

Then after that, you can use `git push` for default push to Bitbucket (master branch).

Answer (score 3):

`git add` only adds the file to your local index so that it is ready to be committed.  You first need to `git commit` (which you did), then `git push` your commits to BitBucket so they will show up there.

You are correct in your belief that you are making commits locally.  This is perhaps one of the defining features of a decentralized version control system (DVCS).  You have a full copy of your project history on your local computer.  When you `git push`, you send the commits you did locally to BitBucket.

Your project folder should have a `.git` directory at its top level.  This is where all the metadata is going.

Comment: I've tried again with a fresh `clone` of my empty project. I then create the file, add it, and commit. Then I run push, enter my password and it says everything is up-to-date. But I don't see *any* files on my BitBucket page after logging in (of course, I give it a moment and refresh)! I know I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What is the result of `git log origin/master`?

Comment: @Oliver The exact instructions are here: confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Sharing+Code+in+Bitbucket .  If they still don't work for you, would you mind updating your question with the exact commands you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: @BenC git log shows you a log of your commits. Origin refers to the origin of your repository (where you cloned it from), and master refers to the branch master in the source repository.

Comment: @Jack Edmonds : which is exactly what he needs : to know what is really on the remote repository...

Comment: @BenC After successfully performing `git push origin master`, then `git log origin/master` shows the file has been transferred.

Comment: @Oliver : it is usually better to write the whole thing, since when you're dealing with more complicated repository structures (multiple remote repositories...), you don't always remember what git will actually do with a default `git push`. Did you get an error with `git push`? What was it? Most of the time the error message is enough to figure out what's wrong, but it's not always very clear for new users.

Comment: @BenC it just said "Everything up-to-date". Now I see a lot of other people have experienced this, as well. But it works now!

Comment: @Oliver : it seems that it actually pushed on another repository/branch... When you do not specify anything, git gets the information from `.git/config`. You should probably take a look at this file in order to find the reason of this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might like to check out these videos at http://www.ava.co.uk/git There are 9 of them, about 4 mins each on average, going through the basics and hopefully flattening a steep learning curve... Feel free to promote this entry if you find the videos beneficial

Answer (score 0):

With Bitbucket you also have the option of using Mercurial which is both easier to use than Git and which keeps it's terminology closer to that of Subversion. I personally do use mostly Git but struggled mightily, and still do, to grasp it's concepts and implementation fully. For me Mercurial is much easier to use and this despite having never used Subversion in the past. I use both Git and Mercurial from the command line so this is not an aversion to the CLI.

Yes your commit is always local with both Git and Mercurial, you then push it to Bitbucket or other server or hosting solution. You may want to read [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/) if you wish to pursue use of Mercurial (may even come in handy with Git since the concepts are similar) at least read the [intro](http://hginit.com/00.html) contrasting distributed SCM to the centralized model. If you want a Git oriented resource or book consider [Pro Git](http://progit.org/book/) but it is not as well written (or as brief) as [Hg Init](http://hginit.com/).